# IOError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, io, download

I am trying to download a link and place it in the downloads folder, however I get a permission error. I am an admin user on the computer and I also ran it in administrator mode. Still I get the same error.

Here is the code I use:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(link, r"C:\Users\%s\Downloads" % (user))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\FTB Server Updater\FTB Updater_v1.0.py", line 28, in <module>
    getNewServer(link)
  File "C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\FTB Server Updater\FTB Updater_v1.0.py", line 22, i getNewServer
    urllib.urlretrieve(lynk, r"C:\Users\%s\Downloads" % (user))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 244, in retrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Grant\\Downloads'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't `urllib.urlretrieve(link, r"C:\Users\%s\Downloads" % (user))` be `urllib.urlretrieve(link, r"C:\Users\%s\Downloads\SAVE_FILE_NAME" % (user))`? You are trying to overwrite the Downloads directory, which I am not sure Windows would allow. It might be possible in unix if you have permissions, but Windows might stop you from doing that!